# Perl DBI failed to delete records

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

I have a database with about 50K records of products. One of the field called price and in some case from the 50K records this field have value of 0 (int).

First I run a query to see how many row exist with price 0 and I got around 4K so I wanted to delete them.

So I have run the following code to delete all records where price = 0

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:MainDatabase.db", "", "", {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1});
$dbh->do("DELETE FROM products WHERE price =0");
```

I have noticed that my database file size did not changed so since I did not got any error, I have run the count query again to see if there is any product with price = 0

the result was 0 which mean the records are deleted.

However, if I open the database with some SQLITE browsers (like the one for mozilla) all records with price = 0 still exist and I can select them.

However, I cannot select them using perl. For perl, these records are simply not there.

Does anyone would have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make a simple test case that demonstrates this behavior. Show both the code you use to create and populate the database, and the code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: to reduce database size after deleting some rows try to run `VACUUM` command

Answer (score 2):

Databases do not reduce the file size just because you deleted some records.  They save that space so that there is a place to insert new records in the future.  Restructuring the whole database just to save a few kilobytes when you delete some rows would be extremely inefficient.

There are ways to make a database reformat to save space, but it's doubtful that you need to worry about this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and that would answer my question related to the file size. But still not explain why after deleting records using perl, for perl these records are deleted, but not for another SQLITE browser.

Comment: @user3473230, is it possible you did not commit the transaction?